# iframe cannot scroll because of setting height in CSS

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a iframe which can display other website.

HTML(.slim):

```
#linked-article-container
  iframe#linked-article frameborder='0' src=@article.external_url
```

CSS(.scss):

```
#linked-article-container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }

  iframe#linked-article {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;

  }
}
```

If I delete the `height: 2000px` in CSS, the scroll will work smoothly. But in this case, the height is only 155px, which makes the iframe not display the whole webpage. How to set the CSS correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: If I'm correct, you want the iframe to be displayed as high as the browser's height? You can use `100vh` for that on `iframe#linked-article`.

Comment: @Roy thanks for answer. the problem still exists, actually if the height is larger than the browser height, the scroll will stop working.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle with your starting point?